# how to add more two end directions on Google Maps Using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

i have more than two location on my data.
how to add more two directions on Google Maps using Laravel

this is code when i use only one directions place

```
Route::get('/maps', function() {
    $config['center'] = 'Telkom Tasikmalaya, Kota Tasikmalaya';
    $config['zoom'] = '16';
    $config['map_height'] = '500px';
    $config['geocodeCaching'] = true;
    $config['scrollwheel'] = false;

    $config['directions'] = true;
    $config['directionsStart'] = 'Telkom Tasikmalaya, Kota Tasikmalaya';
    $config['directionsEnd'] = 'SMK Muhammadiyah, Kota Tasikmalaya';
    $config['directionsEnd'] = 'Alun - Alun, Kota Tasikmalaya';
    $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv';

    GMaps::initialize($config);   

    $map = GMaps::create_map();


    return view('maps')->with('map', $map);
});
```

Comment: what package you use?

Comment: i use " farhanwazir/laravelgooglemaps": "^2.3 " this package